# Task Life Cycle

Tags: project-management

What task life cycle do you follow? and do you mingle tasks and bugs together in the tool you use?  A typical Task life cycle is:

- Not Started - entered but not yet started
- In-Progress - being worked on
- Complete - task is done
  with the exception statuses of:
- On Hold - waiting for something
- Canceled- the task is no longer needed, possibly due to a change in requirements.

The typical bug life cycle could be:

- New - newly entered
- In Progress - being worked on
- QA - going through test
- Client Review - fix being reviewed by the client
- Ready for Promotion - ready for the next release
- Complete - released into production
  with the exception statuses of:
- On-Hold
- Duplicate
  Not Reproducible
- Works as Designed

What's your life cycles?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

I like to keep it simple:

- Pending
- In Risk
- In Production
- Complete

I also have very specific visual aid colors for these tasks, when I list them in systems or Excel spreadsheets, as show above:

[image: Task Colors]

A detailed view of each one:

**Pending** is for tasks I'm stil not working on it, mainly because it *requires* some external event to start it, like some approval or just because I'm not sure that I'll make it anyway.

**In Risk** is for tasks that I did start but they are getting close to a due date and I'm quite away from finishing it. If I'm getting too much In Risk tasks I start to priorize them to get them done in time.

**In Production** is a regular task I'm working on. It maybe doesn't have a due date so it will never get In Risk, or maybe if I delay too much I set a due date and that task can change to In Risk.

**Complete** is pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: does the on-hold exception fall into the in risk category?

Comment: I don't know, never had after it started, probably I would put on Pending again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we manage to have one life cycle for different kind of tasks

- **Open**
- **Working**
- **Rejected**
- **To Be tested**
- **Resolved**
- **Close**

That apply to our tasks based on [ITIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Technology_Infrastructure_Library) (set of concepts and policies for managing information technology (IT) infrastructure, development and operations.):

- **case**
- **change**
- **dependency** (regroup several changes)
- **release** (regroup several dependencies)

Do not forget:

- a **secondary task life cycle** may be needed for certain tasks: for instance, before being opened, worked on, etc., a REL (Release) must be **submitted** first.
- an **approbation** life cycle can come along certain tasks: one can not submit a REL (Release) without an approbation list.

Answer (score 0):

We're using one tool where we do mix bugs and feature requests (but we flag each entry accordingly so we can see whether it's a bug or a requests).

Since we have several departments working on the tasks, we have a litte more statuses...
Our different life cycle statuses are:

- **to specify** (for product management)
- **to reproduce** (for testing, to check e.g. whether something is a software problem or just a misconfiguration by the customer)
- **to develop** (for developers)
- **to test/verify** (for the testing deparment)
- **to document** (for documentation, e.g. to include it in the user manual)
- **implemented & verified** (this is the time when we close the task)
- **restriction / rejection / not reproducable**

Answer (score 0):

The On-hold part is something I've noticed is important - waiting for external dependencies to *get things done* or set up something is, I think, a vital task status for management to easily see what they can go ahead and whip in motion... ^^

Comment: I prefer using "pending" to show it is waiting on someone else.  I use "on hold" to show that no work is to be done on it anymore until further notice.

Comment: Yeah, well - whatever the name ^^ Just not want to forget having it explicitly as a status, separate from the status that says we're going to work on it some time later, compared to we're going to wwork on it when those folks have enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than simple

```
open
error/change analysis
qa review
closed/rejected
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only 2 necessary items are "Open" and "Closed" all the rest are gradients.

I use:

- Open
- Pending
- Resolved
- On Hold
- Closed

Sometimes I add to that:

- In Progress
- Billed
- In Test
- Review
- Cancelled

It depends on the team's work flow.